# iOS beta app got leaked, can I get in trouble with Apple?

Tags: development, app-store-connect

I'm running a beta test for an iOS game. (100 devices, ad-hoc)
Somehow the game got leaked on a site that offers .ipa apps for jailbreaked devices.
Can I get in trouble with Apple because of this? (Can Apple see that the app got installed on more than the usual 100 devices?)

Comment: Do you know if the pirated copy of the app is still signed with your developer certificate? (or is it pinging your analytics servers (or similar) and giving you the numbers of installations?)

Comment: Yes, I guess it's signed with my developer certifictate. (the one for the ad-hoc distribution) However, I can't track the numbers of pirted copy installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is your app, you should probably notify Apple. If you are testing for someone else, notify the developer **and** Apple. It really isn't your fault. To your second question ("Can Apple see the the app got installed on more than the usual 100 devices), I'd say no. Because jailbroken users use methods such as iFunBox or vShare/AppCake, Apple has no way of keeping track of how many times the app was downloaded unless they used the Apple way. Finally, I'd try to find out how your/the app was leaked.

Comment: I could revoke the ad-hoc certificate but that wouldn't stop the app from running on a jailbreaked device, right? It got leaked because a friend gave it to a friend who gave it to friend...Usually it don't care, but I don't want any trouble with Apple.

Comment: @Nadine I wouldn't worry about your cert being on the app if it's stolen and you are not distributing it. Your revoking it won't matter as Jailbreakers don't look at the cert in the first place. Also, I wouldn't worry if you are not adding any of those pirate device ID to your account in iTunes Connect.

Comment: If you choose to notify Apple, you can use the developer support and relate your thinking on it and ask them if your plan to ignore it (or your plan to revoke your cert) is valid / best practice. They might explain how the system works to you or they might say Thanks - you've fine, do what you think is right.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to get it back even you notify Apple because there are so many [Installous alternatives](http://topcydiasources.com/tag/installous/) like those mentioned vshare, appcake, ifunbox, kuaiyong, and those site usually has people download and upload apps. I will sort out why the app is leak if I were you.